# Im trying to make it so the card only opens on the div.card-title instead of the hole div.card (CodePen Home 3D Fold out reveal)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, codepen

I found this 3d card fold on codepen.io [This Link](https://codepen.io/candroo/pen/wKEwRL) and I'm trying to make it to that only when you press `div.card-title` that it opens and not when you press the hole `div.card` especially the small content part when it opens shouldn't be clickable.

If you're able to help me I would appreciate it if you could only show the code you changed to make it easier for me to change in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added comments in the code on the places I have edited it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var zindex = 10;

    $("div.card-title").click(function (e) { //Put the click listner on the .card-title instead of .card
        e.preventDefault();

        var isShowing = false;
        var $element = $(this).parent(".card"); //Get the .card element of the clicked title
        if ($element.hasClass("show")) { //Changed $(this) to $element so it uses the correct element
            isShowing = true
        }

        if ($("div.cards").hasClass("showing")) {
            $("div.card.show")
                .removeClass("show");

            if (isShowing) {
                $("div.cards")
                    .removeClass("showing");
            } else {
                $element //Changed $(this) to $element so it uses the correct element
                    .css({ zIndex: zindex })
                    .addClass("show");

            }

            zindex++;

        } else {
            $("div.cards")
                .addClass("showing");
            $element //Changed $(this) to $element so it uses the correct element
                .css({ zIndex: zindex })
                .addClass("show");

            zindex++;
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you add...

```
if ( !e.target.classList.contains('btn') ) return;
```

Immediately after the preventDefault following click, the clicking anywhere else will have no effect.

Comment: Thats actually a really smart quick fix, I didn't think of this!

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic 'this' problem in javascript. When the user clicks the card, the 'this' is referenced to the card, so you can't simply change the click target to the button, because it will change the context of 'this'.

You change the event listener to the button, and set a variable using jquery's 'parents' method, finding the nearest card - and reconfigure the method without changing too much of the functionality.

```
$("div.card .toggle-info").click(function(e){
```

https://codepen.io/JoeCoulam/pen/eYJLjqJ?editors=1111